# ruby document scope and require relative

Tags: ruby

I am writing a simple script program that uses require, but it's not working as I expected.

Schematic is here:

```
###document_1
-some methods
-require_relative document_2
- print variable defined in document_2
```

document_1 can't read a variable defined in document_2

```
###document_2
a script that calls methods defined in document_1
```

But document_2 can't see the methods in document_1

If someone could help with a link to some good resources explaining ruby document scope, or a short explanation that would be really helpful :)

Comment: Could you please post some reproducible code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local variables are local to the scope they are defined in. Local variables defined in a block are local to that block. Local variables defined in a method are local to that method. Local variables defined in a class are local to that class. Local variables defined in a module are local to that module. Local variables defined in a script are local to that script.

That's why they are called "local" variables, after all!

Comment: thanks. I was assuming that if you included a file you were effectively just adding code to your page

Comment: `require`, `require_once` and `load` simply *run* the script. (Note: `include` is something entirely different, you don't include scripts, you include `Module`s.)